# Passing data to the next page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I faced a problem with going through the pages in angularjs. For some reason all the parameters catch to ids.

```
  angular.module("bookapp").controller("Step1Ctrl", function($scope, stepsdata, $state) {

$scope.steps.set(1)
  $scope.list = [
    {name: 'Chicago', id: 0},
    {name: 'APA', id: 1},
    {name: 'MLA', id: 2},
    {name: 'Harvard', id: 3},
    {name: 'Vancouver', id: 4},
    // {name: 'Vancouver', id: 5},

  ]

  $scope.nextStep = function(item){
    stepsdata.step1 = item.name
    if ($state.params.id){
      if(item.id == 0){
        console.log("Chicago step")
        $state.go('app.steps.two',{id: $state.params.id})}
        if(item.id == 1){
        console.log("APA step")
        $state.go('app.steps.two',{id: $state.params.id})}
        if(item.id == 2){
        console.log("MLA step")
        $state.go('app.steps.two',{id: $state.params.id})}
        if(item.id == 3){
        console.log("Harvard step")
        $state.go('app.steps.two',{id: $state.params.id})}
        if(item.id == 4){
        console.log("Vancouver")
        $state.go('app.steps.two',{id: $state.params.id})}

      else{
        console.log("other city")
      }
    } else {
      $state.go('app.steps.two')
    }

  }

})
```

The console says "other city" all the time, no matter what city I click on.
Can you tell me why??

Comment: looking at the logic it seems like your $state.params.id is null, could you log that to the console and check? Also what do you mean by all params "catch" to Ids?

Comment: when I click to the Chicago button, the console says "chicago step" and other city", when I click to the APA button, the console says "APA step" and other city"... looks like it catches id from the right parameter and then a null parameter all the time

Comment: I think you are missing a closing brace before the else. What does the "other city" else match to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `else if` for other options

```
if (item.id == 0) {
  console.log("Chicago step")
  $state.go('app.steps.two', { id: $state.params.id })
}
else if (item.id == 1) {
  console.log("APA step")
  $state.go('app.steps.two', { id: $state.params.id })
}
else if (item.id == 2) {
  console.log("MLA step")
  $state.go('app.steps.two', { id: $state.params.id })
}
else if (item.id == 3) {
  console.log("Harvard step")
  $state.go('app.steps.two', { id: $state.params.id })
}
else if (item.id == 4) {
  console.log("Vancouver")
  $state.go('app.steps.two', { id: $state.params.id })
}

else {
  console.log("other city")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `if`s with `else if`s. In that case each and every `if` is not checked.

```
if(item.id == 0){
    console.log("Chicago step")
    $state.go('app.steps.two',{id: $state.params.id})
}
else if(item.id == 1){
    console.log("APA step")
    $state.go('app.steps.two',{id: $state.params.id})
}
else if(item.id == 2){
    console.log("MLA step")
    $state.go('app.steps.two',{id: $state.params.id})
}
else if(item.id == 3){
    console.log("Harvard step")
    $state.go('app.steps.two',{id: $state.params.id})
}
else if(item.id == 4){
    console.log("Vancouver")
    $state.go('app.steps.two',{id: $state.params.id})
}
else{
    console.log("other city")
}
```

In your existing case, say you click on `Chicago`, the `if` for `item.id == 0` is executed, but the control doesn't exit at this point. The other `if`s conditions are also checked. The `else` part is matched to the `if` for Vancouver and hence that too is executed (To be clear, the current else is as good as writing `if(item.id !== 4 )`)

Here is the flow when you click `Chicago`:

```
id == 0 -> YES -> Execute if block
id == 1 -> NO -> Skip
id == 2 -> NO -> Skip
id == 3 -> NO -> Skip
-----------
id == 4 -> NO -> Skip
else (i.e. id != 4) -> YES -> Execute block
-------
```